# Get the Socket Descriptor in Node.js

Tags: node.js, sockets

I would like to open a socket in Node.js and then start a groups of sub-processes with the child inheriting the socket descriptor.

I created a server with `new net.Server()` but the resulting object does not expose the socket descriptor. If I can get the descriptor, I can forward the descriptor to the child process.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you cannot do this because Windows doesn't support it, and Node is aiming for the identical interface on all platforms.

See the following issue: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3025

Comment: This is definitely possible. Look at the way the Node.js cluster module is implemented. A file descriptor is passed from the parent process to all of the worker processes in the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible. Look at the way the Node.js cluster module is implemented. A file descriptor is passed from the parent process to all of the worker processes in the cluster.

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/cluster/master.js